# Password Always Returning Invalid

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
    import java.util.*;  
    import java.lang.String;  
    import java.lang.Character;  

    public class password {  
        public static void main(String[] args) {  
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
            System.out.print("Please enter a Password: ");  
            String password = input.next();  
            if (isValid(password))  
            {   
            System.out.println("valid Password");  
            System.out.print("Please verify your Password: ");  
            String vrfypassword = input.next();

            if (vrfypassword.equals(password)){
             System.out.println("Password Verfied");
             } else {
             System.out.println("Unable to verify password");
            }
            }
            else 
            {  
                System.out.println("InValid Password"); 
            } 

        }  
        public static boolean isValid(String password) {  
            if (password.length() < 10) {   
            return false;  
            } else {      
                char c;  
                int count = 1;   
                for (int i = 0; i < password.length() - 1; i++) {  
                    c = password.charAt(i);  
                    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {          
                        return false;  
                    } else if (!Character.isDigit(c))   
                        return false;      
                }  
            }  
            return true;  
        }  
    }
```

Im not sure why but it always is returning a invalid password even when i use a password that "should" go through. The requirements are less than 10 characters, one letter, and one number. Is there anything im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (password.length() < 10) { return false; }
```

> The requirements are less than 10 characters

Your requirement isn't reflected in the code.

Invert the statement:

```
if (password.length() > 10) { return false; }
```

And this:

```
if (!Character.isDigit(c)) { return false; }
```

curses at this:

> The requirements are less than 10 characters, one letter, and one number

Just leave this check away.

Try this:

```
public static boolean isValid(String password) {  
        if (password.length() < 10) {   
            return false;  
        } else {      
            char c;  
            int digitCount, letterCount;   
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {  
                c = password.charAt(i);  
                if (Character.isLetter(c)) {          
                    letterCount++; 
                } else if (Character.isDigit(c))   
                    digitCount++;      
            }  
            if(digitCount < 1 || lettercount < 1) { return false; }
        }  
        return true;  
    }
```

Comment: Switched it around, Thanks! But it still returns false s:

Comment: Ah yeah that's much better. Had to set digitCount and letterCount to 0 or else i was getting "variable "" might not have been initialized"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, whenever there is a **letter** in the password, it will return `false`, because of this clause:

```
...
else if (!Character.isDigit(c)){
    System.out.println("H2");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
           if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {          
                    return false;  
                } else if (!Character.isDigit(c))   
                    return false;      
            }
```

to

```
          if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {          
                    return false;  
          }
```

Comment: Perfect. Not sure why I did that. Thank you

Comment: This will return `false` for special symbols, which is nowhere indicated. Neither will this make sure you have at least 1 digit and 1 letter.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're reading \r or \n from the input.
This is neither digit, nor letter and might break things.

Also is this correct:

```
i < password.length() - 1
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
i < password.length()
```